# Should All or Most Words in a Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange Question be Capitalized?

Tags: style, capitalization

I thought all or a majority of words need to be capitalized when it's a title. The form that I fill out to ask a question on here says title and after the question is submitted it's displayed using a larger font. Therefore I see this a cue to capitalize all or a majority of words in the title.

I was surprised to see a user recommend that I use sentence casing for one of my questions and for another one it got edited to use sentence casing where only the first word is uppercase. Are they right or wrong for doing that? What's going on here?

Comment: Yes, You Should Capitalize All the Words if You Want Your Question to Look Slightly Pretentious. On the other hand, using normal capitalization is perfectly OK.

Comment: Cross site duplicate: [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98066), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314924) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252624). Consensus: don't.

Comment: @alephzero even worse, I read that like William Shatner would say it.    "Yes.  You.  Should.  Capiltalise.   All.  The.  Words..."  etc like each word is a separate sentence with a trailing gap.

Comment: Word to the wise: capitalize the first word and only other words that take a capital letter like English. sentence casing?? Like a sausage?//Should all or most words Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange be capitalized?

Comment: Hi! Which words **shouldn't** be capitalized? According to which standards? You wrote the words or, in, a, and be non-capitalized..

Answer (score 24):

No.  The title of a question is not like a book title, but more like a sectional heading. It should be written as a sentence and use sentence case.

Title case is used in such thing as titles of books. For example: "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone"  (Note that little words like "and", "the" aren't capitalised)

Some newspapers use title case for headlines. It is more common in the USA.  Here we use title case for the title of this website:  "StackExchange English Language Learners"  (and style StackExchange in camel case)

But the titles of questions are really "headings". They should normally be written in sentence case, and use sentence grammar.  So write a question like:

> Should each word in a StackExchange question title be capitalized?

and not a headline:

> Words Capitalized on StackExchange

Comment: "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone" could arguably be considered either (partial) title case or sentence case, depending on whether you consider "the Philosopher's Stone" to be a proper noun.

Comment: @NotThatGuy It's title case, it just looks the same as sentence case would if you do consider "the Philosopher's Stone" to be a proper noun. Cf. "the prisoner of Azkaban."

Comment: Stack Exchange is two words, both capitalised, not one written as camel case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wZDI.jpg

Comment: Yes, and these two words are styled as a single word in camel case.

Comment: @James K that's not camelCase. stackExchange is camelCase (with a hump in the middle), StackExchange is PascalCase.

Comment: [As a name, Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow" (two words, capital letters). … Currently, all Stack Exchange Network sites follow this convention: Server Fault, Super User, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)

Comment: @JamesK no, they aren’t ever styled as 1 word. They are always written as two words.

Comment: +1 for **a question is not comparable to a book title**. A title of a book had to stand out in a bookshop, especially on shelves when stacked together and only their [spines are on display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_design#/media/File:Bookspine.jpg).  An SE question is not the title of a subgenre, it does not announce or introduce a larger topic anything, it is just one of many thousands of listed questions or statements.

Comment: Everything you say may be correct, but I see no source - isn't this just your opinion?

Comment: @Mari-LouA how is a question on an index page different from a book on a shelf? Questions titles introduce an idea (or rather, a problem), and *because* they are one in a horde of questsions, they (just like books in a store) want to stand out.

Comment: @JacobRaihle  On SE questions appear on sites specific to that topic. The post stands out just fine because it appears on a single page which you scroll down. We can, I hope, agree that writing in all caps looks bad, although it helps the Q stand out from the crowd, we see it as rude and similar to shouting. Capitalizing every word on a *long* Q would also look bad, it does not make it easier for the reader. A question or statement is only that, it does not introduce an article, a paper, a study, or a story.  Have you ever seen an exam  question or essay title where every word is capitalized?

Comment: @Mari-LouA A question stands by itself on its own page, yes, but on, for example, the "Top Questions" page it is just one of many. Questions on an SE site are all related, but books on a shelf tend to be, too: by genre and author. I don't use title case, so I'm not arguing that question titles should be written in title case, but I can't see the distinction between questions and books (except that book spines have many more design choices available than SE questions). If I *did* use title case, I suspect that I would find question titles to be an appropriate application.

Comment: @JacobRaihle  `I don't use title case, so I'm not arguing that question titles should be written in title case` it appears that you are arguing. A question or a statement *should* follow the basic rules of grammar and syntax., it is not a newspaper headline. Headlines are normally succinct and eliminate prepositions, articles, conjunctions, etc. and use shorter words. Book titles are not normally sentences, publishers/editors/authors do not use a full stop/period in titles. There will always be exceptions of course.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm arguing that a question on a question index page - in its desire to stand out and quickly communicate *something* - is analogous to a book on a shelf, and that if title case is valid for one, it's valid for the other. It's sensible to make a distinction *if* the question title is written as a sentence (which most book titles are not), but that's not a given. A *question body* should follow basic rules of grammar, but I don't see why a *question title* must - and while many do, at least a large minority *don't*.

Comment: "It should be written as a sentence" except for punctuation: it shouldn't end with a full stop/period, although it should have a question mark if appropriate.

Comment: @user6916458: (1) Are you talking to anybody in particular? To reply to a specific comment author, please use the “@” notation to notify that person.  (2) “I see no source”. My entire comment is a link to its source.

Comment: @Scott I was referring to the question I commented on (and thus thought the @ notation wasn't needed, my bad!) :)

Comment: @user6916458: No, it’s cool. I’m not sure whether you’re even supposed to use “@” notation to notify the author of the post. But when you’re adding the ninth comment under a post (or even the third) and it uses the word “you”, it can be helpful to clarify who you’re addressing. I saw your comment below mine and jumped to the conclusion that you were talking to me.

Answer (score 13):

Use of capitals in titles is much more common in the US than in Britain; I've no idea what the conventions are in other countries. In the UK, people find the typography of headlines in US newspapers (today's NYT has *Now It’s Not Safe at Home Either. Wildfires Bring Ashen Air Into the House*) jarring and rather antiquated (and no-one knows why "at" and "the" are treated differently from "It's" and "Into"). StackOverflow has an international user base, and although it has an American bias in some areas (such as its selection of Captchas), it avoids dictating that its members should use American spelling or typography.

Comment: A really quick peek at some Canadian and Australian newspapers/sites indicates they don't capitalize (almost) every word either: https://www.thestar.com/ https://www.theglobeandmail.com/  https://www.news.com.au/ https://www.theaustralian.com.au/ Of course that's still not every English-speaking country but I guess those are the largest ones.

Comment: "at" and "the" are treated differently because they're connecting words (preposition and article, respectively), meaning they're less important. Although "Into" is also a preposition, so IDK why it's capitalized. "It" is a pronoun, so it has to be capitalized.

Comment: While (I presume) nothing in this answer is factually inaccurate, I kind of doubt that this is the reason most people write question titles in sentence case. I suspect that a lot of American question-askers, even among those who are familiar with casing conventions, will also write their question titles in sentence case, and I also suspect the reason James K identified is a likely explanation.

Comment: I thought India was the largest English speaking country? Of course they have many other languages as well.

Comment: Ah, it seems that India would be second to the US, now that I look it up.

Comment: @wjandrea: I think Michael Kay well knows that “at” and “the” are uncapitalised because the convention is to leave a certain small class of words uncapitalised (articles, conjunctions, certain prepositions…).  The point is that it’s a very mysterious and arbitrary convention, even by the standards of the many arbitrary conventions of English orthography.

Comment: I know there is a convention used by American publishers, but I've never worked out exactly what it is.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs, well, yes indeed. My bad.

Comment: I still don't know why the [BBC uses Nasa](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/488580) but not Bbc

Comment: @uhoh Because NASA is pronounced Nasa, and BBC is pronounced BeeBeeCee

Comment: @JacobRaihle ah! Yes I'll buy that, thanks!

Comment: Might not even be a American vs British thing. The AMS style guide (American Math Society) actually asks for sentence case headings. This might be for consistency purposes though because Math variables are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 7):

You are asking this on a language-related SE site, but in addition to language, this could be seen as a question about the customs on SE. (Along with such questions as "should one include 'Hello' and 'Thank you' as part of questions posted here".)

From that viewpoint, the answer is easy to gather: just now, I glanced at the "Hot Network Questions" list, and the question list on the front page of ell.stackexchange.com, both had just one question with All Words Uppercased in total, this one. The edits and comments you've received are also an indicator of that. Having all words capitalized makes this question stand out from the list, and not in a good way.

Answer (score 4):

I think it’s up to the discretion of the asker.

You can read up on different ways to use case in titles, as I believe there are a few different ways of doing this; there are probably strict guidelines you can follow in academia.

For the question you have asked here, I think ordinary sentence case would be acceptable, as you’ve phrased it as a complete sentence/question, but it’s also acceptable as a title.

You could also phrase it as more of a title, and use title case, e.g.:

> Capitalisation in Stack Exchange Questions

In that case, I’d be much more likely to do it in a title case, as above.

Answer (score 1):

A Stack Exchange title is often written as a question, and therefore it is preferred to not use title case.

Often or not, capitalisation of titles and headings is a convention rather than a set rule. For example, the APA style requires title case for all headings. However, AMS asks for sentence case headings (capitalize first word only). I actually lost marks on an assignment recently because I followed the AMS convention (I'm a Math/CS major) when the guidelines said title case.

Answer (score 0):

If it ends with a punctuation mark it's a sentence and should be capitalised as such (leading word and proper nouns only).

If it doesn't end with a punctuation mark it's a title, and significant words should have an initial capital.

Comment: An interesting rule. Citation Needed

Comment: Offered as a concise suggestion rather than an established rule.